# Are there limitations on devilbound creatures?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters

I am confused about [Devilbound creatures](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/devilbound-creature), which seems terribly overpowered. Especially the pit fiend bound ones.

A creature bound to a pit fiend is able to throw quickened fireballs three times a day, and a blasphemy once a day. This potentially means you could have a 5HD monster throwing around *7th level spells*.

Am I missing something, or is there an errata somewhere? Is there something preventing a 5HD creature being bound to a pit fiend?

Comment: Additional question that would have made it sound somewhat opinionated: is it just a terribly written template that I should avoid using as a GM?

Comment: Probably not a good idea to use comments as a way of adding bits of questions you aren't sure you want to ask, as the chances are it will get deleted, and it kind of goes against how the system is supposed to work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**That's Pretty Much How It Works**

> "Devilbound creature" is an acquired template that can be added to **any creature with 5 or more Hit Dice and Intelligence, Wisdom, and Charisma scores of 3 or higher** (referred to hereafter as the base creature). The creature retains all the base creature's statistics and special abilities except as noted here.

Emphasis mine. There's absolutely nothing by RAW stopping you from doing this. Is it a good idea? Probably not. As a DM you should exercise caution and compare the capabilities of the monster to the party you're placing it up against. But RAW-wise you're right on the money - fifth level monsters, 7th level spells as SLAs. Welcome to RAW.

Comment: A note on the template: It says the creature The creature uses _its Hit Dice or caster level, whichever is higher, as the caster level for its spell-like abilities_. A fifth level moster would cast those abilities at fifth caster level, making them lose some punch, specially in the case of blasphemy. However, 3/day fireball as a quick action are still worrysome, even if the are only 5D6.